# which type of sorting is done in the SQL ORDER BY statement

Tags: sql-server, sorting

My question is if there are any sorting is used when we use `SQL` `ORDER BY` statement then which sorting is used (like quick or merge)?

And is it will be faster to sort a linked list or an array containing the results using quick or merge sort rather than sorting using `SQL` `OREDR BY` statement?

Comment: You're comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: Tim's right. But, if you are curious, I've found [this](http://sqlperformance.com/2015/04/sql-plan/internals-of-the-seven-sql-server-sorts-part-1) article (check also part 2) very interesting.